# How to safely store the Auth. Provider metadata in the git repository without revealing its secret?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, continuous-integration, ci

I have an `authprovider` metadata stored in Git repo with the following body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AuthProvider xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <authorizeUrl>https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Site-Name/_layouts/15/OauthAuthorize.aspx</authorizeUrl>
    <consumerKey>SHAREPOINT_CONTUMER_KEY</consumerKey>
    <consumerSecret>SHAREPOINT_CONSUMER_SECRET</consumerSecret>
    <friendlyName>Sharepoint Account Site</friendlyName>
    <includeOrgIdInIdentifier>false</includeOrgIdInIdentifier>
    <providerType>MicrosoftACS</providerType>
    <sendAccessTokenInHeader>false</sendAccessTokenInHeader>
    <sendClientCredentialsInHeader>false</sendClientCredentialsInHeader>
    <sendSecretInApis>true</sendSecretInApis>
    <tokenUrl>https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/mycompany.onmicrosoft.com/tokens/OAuth/2?resource=00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/mycompany.sharepoint.com@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com</tokenUrl>
</AuthProvider>
```

As you can notice, I replaced `<consumerKey>` and `<consumerSecret>` nodes with placeholder values to keep them away from the public access of all repo's users.

I also would like to keep it this way all along to have the full repo-based CI set for my environment. Unfortunately, when deploying to an empty Sandbox (potentially a Scratch Org), I receive the following error:

> force-app\credentials\authproviders\SharepointAccountSite.authprovider-meta.xml  You must enter a value

I'm sure it's because of these two values, as after changing them to the original ones, the metadata deploys just fine.

So I wanted to ask whether there is any way to store these files in a repo without revealing the key and secret? Or this must be entirely a manual process?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no there is no other way apart from manual process. Though retrieved key is in encrypted format it can be deployed to any sandbox and read. In managed package we can keep consuerSecret field blank. Ideally same provision should be there for this also from Salesforce.

Comment: One way is CI/CD using GH Actions: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets . There are a number of other options, SO and other SE forums have good Q&As on this.